Superset HandleBar support for array type Column iteration
I have a requirements to create dynamic table on the basis of array type columns in my data. Both array type column have the same number of attributes.
Image shows actual running code
Image shows reference dataset with datatype
Actual data in sqllab
Here Column D AND E which I pointed in my dataset are array type columns.
{{#each data}}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>REG</th>
            <th>TYPE</th>
            <th>STO</th>
            {{#each D}}
                <th>{{this}}% </th>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{A}}</td>
            <td>{{B}}</td>
            <td>{{C}}</td>
            {{#each E}}
                <td>{{this}}</td>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </table>
{{/each}}

I was expecting it create dynamic header in table HTML attribute, but it did not create anything, if I just reference D and E, it shows be array data in square bracket.

I don't think you have provided enough information here. What is the shape of data?

@76484 I have edited post with few more detailed images as I replicated issue in local, The data type of column is text Array which is supported by postgres which I am trying to iterate and create dynamic columns.
